# How to unlock y axis and rotate it infinatly in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using orbital controls in three js and by default it allows you to rotate only 180 degrees by y-axis I want to unlock it so I could rotate my camera infinitely by y-axis didn't relay worked with 3D before so have no clue what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrbitControls` has a restriction when transforming the camera because of the internal usage of `lookAt()`. This essentially means the class is not able to move the camera "over the poles".

If you need such a behavior, use `TrackballControls` instead.